# Search entire sdcard for a specific file

Tags: java, android, file, search

I know how to search a file, but using a specific path, example /sdcard/picture/file. Is there a way to search for that specific file. Example: search for file. Then the app locate it in /sdcard/picture. Then erase it.

Any help?  Thanks (I know how to erase a file, but have to write the entire path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve that problem recursively starting from the root directory of the external storage / SD card.

Some untested code out of my head (method names could be wrong)

```
public File findFile(File dir, String name) {
    File[] children = dir.listFiles();

    for(File child : children) {
        if(child.isDirectory()) {
           File found = findFile(child, name);
           if(found != null) return found;
        } else {
            if(name.equals(child.getName())) return child;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you want to find *all* occurrences of that file name on your SD card you'll have to use a List for collecting and returning all found matches.

Comment: Trying this one, but getFiles(); is unknown method for java.io.File and every one that I try says that cant be use with java.io.File[]

Comment: Well... as I said, this is untested code for illustrating the general concept of solving that problem recursively. Anyway. I updated my example with the correct function call.

Comment: Ok thanks, one last question dir is the sdcard? If not what is it?

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); will give you the sdcard, make sure you have the required permissions!

Comment: Where does this code returns the file path of the searched file??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File root = new File("/sdcard/");
        String fileName = "a.txt";
        try {
            boolean recursive = true;

            Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, null, recursive);

            for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                File file = (File) iterator.next();
                if (file.getName().equals(fileName))
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    file.delete();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting unknown entity from FileUtils

Comment: This is because above example is not directly targeted at Android development. [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) is a component from the Apache Commons library. Furthermore be careful and do not hard-code paths to the external storage. There is no guarantee, that all devices have their external storage mounted in a directory called "/sdcard/". You need to use [SDK methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) for getting the proper path.

Comment: And what about search entire files? Even phone ones?