# Delete an application (*.apk) after installation

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I've created an android application, and exported it as `*.apk`. Is it possible to make the `apk` file to be deleted automatically upon successful installation?

Comment: Delete the APK from where?

Comment: From SD/Disk. Since I'm giving the APK to my friends for beta testing.

Comment: but some applications like bluetooth app sender they get it again ur apk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are installing some other APK downloading through you application and want to remove if after successful install, follow me :-)

Step 1:
declare following permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_ADDED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_CHANGED" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
```

Step 2: 
Register Receiver

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.az.appstore.InstallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />


                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Step 4:

In your Installer activity create a hash map like this, I have created in `ApplicationMain`, it will differ according to implementation.

```
public static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, File> INSTALL_APK_INFO = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, File>();
```

and fill it with package name and file, where apk is put. You can get Pacakage name from any apk using this method

```
public static String getPackageNameForAPK(final String archiveFilePath, Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(archiveFilePath, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            return info.packageName;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Step 5: 
Now on your install receiver just do this

```
if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)) {
            ApplicationInfo info = null;
            try {
                info = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(intent.getDataString().split(":")[1], PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (info != null) {
                    File file = ApplicationMain.INSTALL_APK_INFO.get(info.packageName);
                    if (file != null) {
                        file.delete();
                        ApplicationMain.INSTALL_APK_INFO.remove(info.packageName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Summary**

1) create a hashmap and populate it with the APK package name and file. File is where exactly your APK is present.

Request to install APK

```
public static void installUpdateAPK(Context context, String pathToAPK) {

        pathToAPK = pathToAPK.replace("file:///", "");

        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(pathToAPK);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), APK_MIME_TYPE);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        String name = getPackageNameForAPK(pathToAPK, context);

        if (name != null) {
            ApplicationMain.INSTALL_APK_INFO.put(name, file);
        }
    }
```

2) Register Package added, changed, install intents

3) On your receiver get the the package name that is installed from `Intent`

4) Get the file object from your hashmap and just call `delete()`

Comment: What is the package to import ApplicationMain? I tried searching but couldn't find any.

Comment: @thepace please see "step 4" you can declare this map in any class, I have declared it in ApplicationMain

Comment: If you remember this do you have any idea why it does not work on Android 6 and down?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter whether the APK is deleted from the device's SD-Card after the installation is complete. Even if such a function could be programmed in the app, any user with a rooted device will **always** be able to access the APK from the `/data/app/` system partition. Which effectively nullifies your effort to delete the APK in the first place.

That being said, you could add a function that will delete the APK on the first run. Since the APK could be saved / stored just about anywhere on the sd-card, I think these questions *should* help you with that.

To find a file: [Search entire sdcard for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11386848/450534)

To delete the file once found: [How to delete a file from SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1248292/450534)

Answer (score 2):

If you know where the apk was downloaded to on the device, then you can delete it once installed when your app is first run. If it is on the SD Card, you will need permission to write to it.

However, if you don't know where it is saved, then at best you will have to scan the device for an apk file with the name you gave it and delete it.

Additionally, once installed, apks are copied over to the internal storage. Any user with a rooted device will be able to recover your apk.

Beta testing is a matter of trust. If you do not trust the people who you are giving the apk to for testing, do not give it to them.

Answer (score -1):

when the application starts you can check the sdcard/download folder (or other place where you might save the apk) manuallly. then delete that from there.

To avoid searching in every run you can store a first_run field in your shared preference. Set the field true by default and after first run set it false. So that you can detect the first runt

Comment: From the application you can not detect whether it is installed. So the best way is to do it manually .. see my edited answer